# Make Zend 2 to only search for templates in same Module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

I have (simplified) two modules, `Application` and `Admin`. I have worked on the `Admin` module for a while now and started with `Application`. Both the modules feature a controller named `UsersController`.

Now as I started to make the `Application` and created some routes and actions, my `Admin` module broke. The error I got when trying to open any admin page everywhere was similar to

```
Unable to render template "application/users/index"
```

According to [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#controllers-and-view-models), the first part of the template path is taken from the namespace of the calling controller. But ever since I created the directory `module/Application/view/application/users/`, it tries to take all the `Admin\Controller\UsersController` templates from there, without regard to the namespace.

How can I make Zend to use the namespace again, without having to force the template file in the action every time?

(Using Zend 2.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I used the same aliases for Controller names in more than one module. So I changed their names like this:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'AdminIndex' => 'Admin\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
```

The other module config used the same names and thus just overrode the ones from my Admin module.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Admin;

class Module
{
    public function init($moduleManager)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $actionName = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action');
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controller->layout(__DIR__ . "/Application/view/application/user/$actionName");
        }, 100);
    }
}
```